# Sent and receive tcp message in bash

Tags: bash

I need make code to send and receive tcp message in bash script. I know I can use

```
echo -n "REMOTE QCH" >/dev/tcp/IP/PORT
```

to send message but what next?

Response from server can be

```
@QCH OK 01/14
```

or

```
@QCH OK 01/01
```

I need make something like this:

```
if "response message is more then > 01 #01 is number after / in this case 14 "@QCH OK 01/14" 14 is more then 01, run command"
then
fi
```

I hope someone understand me :) thx

Comment: Why do you want to do this directly in bash? Wouldn't a simple C+sockets program be easier?

Comment: or Perl, or Python, or any of a dozen other more feature-ful but still simple scripting languages... but if it's reading and writing on the same port, couldn't you just read from that? Maybe a `while read` loop or something? Looks like simple text...

Answer (score 0):

The following simulates random responses of the form you specified and handles them according to logic you would need to specify.

```
#!/bin/sh

eval_response(){
    read response

    testor=`echo "${response}" |
    awk -v pref="@QCH OK 01/" '{ 
        print "\n Response = ", $0 | " cat >&2" ;
        pMatch=index( $0, pref ) ;
        if( pMatch > 0 ){
            rPos=length(pref)+1 ;
            rCode=substr( $0, rPos ) ;
            print rCode ;
            exit ;
        }else{
            print "uknw" ;
        } ;
    }' `
    case ${testor} in
        01 ) echo "\t no action required." ;;
        uknw ) action_tbd ;;
        * ) class_specific_action ;;
    esac
}

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
RESP_SCENARIOS="${BASE}.cmd_resp"


cat >"${RESP_SCENARIOS}" <<-!EnDoFiNpUt
@QCH OK 01/01
@QCH OK 01/02
@QCH OK 01/03
@QCH JACK
@QCH OK 01/04
@QCH OK 01/05
@QCH OK 01/06
@QCH INGRID
@QCH OK 01/07
@QCH OK 01/08
@QCH OK 01/09
@QCH GEORGE
@QCH OK 01/10
@QCH OK 01/11
@QCH OK 01/12
@QCH FRED
@QCH OK 01/13
@QCH OK 01/14
@QCH OK 01/15
@QCH JILL
@QCH OK 01/16
!EnDoFiNpUt

action_tbd(){
    echo "\t action for unknown condition encountered."
}

class_specific_action(){
    echo "\t Action for response class '${testor}'."
}


while [ true ]
do
    #CMD='echo -n "REMOTE QCH" >/dev/tcp/IP/PORT'
    shuf --head-count=1 "${RESP_SCENARIOS}"
    sleep 1
done |
while [ true ]
do
    eval_response
done
```

The session log for the execution is as follows:

```
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$ ./test_43.sh

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/02
     Action for response class '02'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/14
     Action for response class '14'.

 Response =  @QCH FRED
     action for unknown condition encountered.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/06
     Action for response class '06'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/14
     Action for response class '14'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/15
     Action for response class '15'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/05
     Action for response class '05'.

 Response =  @QCH GEORGE
     action for unknown condition encountered.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/11
     Action for response class '11'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/03
     Action for response class '03'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/10
     Action for response class '10'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/13
     Action for response class '13'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/01
     no action required.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/06
     Action for response class '06'.

 Response =  @QCH OK 01/13
     Action for response class '13'.
^C  (manually interrupted)
ericthered@OasisMega1:/0__WORK$
```